# Azure yml Deployment successful. artifact is published , but not consumed. unable to access apis

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a simple spring boot application via the Azure Yml pipeline. the deployment is successful but the URL only shows the default Microsoft webpage and says I need to deploy the code. in the pipeline, my artifact is published, but not consumed. the artifact is packaged as .jar file. app service uses zip deployment. i don't know how to make sure the artifact is packaged as zip , not jar.

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxx'
  webAppName: 'yyyyyyy'

stages:
  - stage: BuildApplication
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: Maven@3
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
              mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
              jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
              jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
              goals: 'package'

          - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:
              targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              ArtifactName: 'drop'
              publishLocation: 'Container'

  - stage: DeployApplication
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: webApp'
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add one more task on your `BuildApplication` stage to zip your output of the build step.

For example you could use the `Archive files` task and specify the folder on which the .jar files are located. You should change the `rootFolderOrFile` variable. The zip output will be located on `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' with the name '$(Build.BuildId).zip`

As you publish your `ArtifactStagingDirectory` inside this folder your BuildId.zip will contain your files. The deployment step should work without additional changes.

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

Comment: i added this step. it generated the zip file. but no success. same issue. the artifact does not gets consumed. 
i don't know if I need to change anything here: 
packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'

Comment: this is what i get as logs in deployment.

Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'fregtest1'

Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"1"}

App Service Application settings are already present.

Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.

Successfully deployed web package to App Service.

NOTE: Run From Package makes wwwroot read-only, so you will receive an error when writing files to this directory.

App Service Application URL: http://fregtest1.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Change the `packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip'`

Answer (score 0):

Well if your application is maven based, you should get jar/war file.

- step1:- Rename the file as ROOT.war/ROOT.jar.
- step2:- change deploy    webapp task as below.

`packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.war'`
`packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.jar'`
based on your artifact output.

Comment: even when i use packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.jar', i get the same issue.  somehow the deployment is not able to consume my artifacts

Comment: @amritchhetri, Don't forget to rename artifact as ROOT.jar, faced similar issue initially. Try to give absolute path by adding a bash task, do ls & pwd commands. If this doesn't work, try it out in classic editor and then shift to yaml.

Comment: do you have example on how you manage to rename the artifact?

Comment: Hi @amritchhetri, do not make a zip file. It won't help. For Rename use bash task. Add the command:- `mv $yourFilename.jar ROOT.jar`. Deploy with jar/war, zip won't work.